# Accessing saved pictures on windows phone 8

Tags: c#, image, file, windows-phone-8, load

I'm saving images like this

```
BitmapImage img = (BitmapImage)Bild.Source;
                WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap(img);
                String tempJPEG = "TempJPEG.jpg";
                var myStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
                if (myStore.FileExists(tempJPEG))
                {
                    myStore.DeleteFile(tempJPEG);
                }
                IsolatedStorageFileStream myFileStream = myStore.CreateFile(tempJPEG);

                Extensions.SaveJpeg(wb, myFileStream, wb.PixelWidth, wb.PixelHeight, 0, 85);
                myFileStream.Close();

                myFileStream = myStore.OpenFile(tempJPEG, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

                String picname = "";
                picname += DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString();
                picname += ".jpg";

                MediaLibrary library = new MediaLibrary();
                Picture pic = library.SavePicture(picname, myFileStream);

                BitmapImage bm = new BitmapImage();
                MessageBox.Show("Images successfully saved!");
```

Now im trying to load all the images i've saved from this function, they get stored in "Saved Pictures" in the Photo Library. 
So far i got this code

```
        using (var library = new MediaLibrary())
        {

            PictureAlbumCollection allAlbums = library.RootPictureAlbum.Albums;

            PictureAlbum cameraRoll = allAlbums.Where(album => album.Name == "Saved Pictures").FirstOrDefault();

            var CameraRollPictures = cameraRoll.Pictures;

        }
```

but cameraRoll becomes Null everytime.

So how should i go about loading the pictures into my app?

Answer (score 1):

here's an example for you :
(I've tested and it works very well.)

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnalioto/archive/2011/01/28/10121728.aspx

Another thing, make sure your capability for accessing photo lib added :

```
<!-- For accessing photos in the media library. -->
<Capability Name="ID_CAP_MEDIALIB_PHOTO" />
```

Hope it helps.